# an AI text completer similar to tabnine

Tags: chrome, text-processing, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for an AI text completion extension for the browser that would display the next sentence like [TabNine](https://www.tabnine.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the [text prediction feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2lhk.jpg) in Windows 10:

[image]

FYI:

- [How can I increase the number of words suggested by the text prediction feature in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1730838/116475)

Comment: And windows 11?

Comment: @Eddisch most likely windows 11 too but I haven't tried it there

Comment: found it in the time and language section. but i'm still waiting for other answers

Comment: @Eddisch thanks yes that'd be great to have other solutions as the text prediction feature in Windows has some annoying limitations.